# C# WPF Adding items to listview keeps overwriting existing data

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, listview, observablecollection

I am fairly new to C#. I have a `MainWindow` which contains a `ListView` (lvStores), furthermore, I have a button that will open another window (NewStoreWindow). The `NewStoreWindow` contains 2 textboxes and an OK button. When I write something in the textboxes and press OK, the window is is rightfully closing and adding to my `ListView`. However, when I try to add a new item to the `ListView`, after adding the first, it will just overwrite it. Or actually, it will remove it, and then it will add the next one. I believe it has to do with my `ObservableCollection`. I have tried to put them in my `public MainWindow()` but then the code wouldn't execute. Furthermore, I have tried to use `List` instead of `ObservableCollection`.

**Snippet of MainWindow code**

```
private void cmdNewStore_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (m_blnBusy)
            {
                return;
            }

            // Open NewStoreWindow in a new window
            NewStoreWindow newStore = new NewStoreWindow();
            newStore.ShowDialog();

            ObservableCollection<AddListViewItem> lvColumnList = new ObservableCollection<AddListViewItem>();
            ObservableCollection<AddListViewItem> items = (ObservableCollection<AddListViewItem>)lvStores.ItemsSource;
            lvStores.ItemsSource = lvColumnList;

            switch (SLvCol)
            {
                // If CSV is NOT loaded on start up and listview is then empty
                case false:

                    // If no items exist in listview
                    if (items == null)
                    {
                        // Add item from textbox from NewStoreWindow
                        lvColumnList.Add(new AddListViewItem() {sID = SNewStoreTbid, sName = SNewStoreTbName});
                        lvStores.ItemsSource = lvColumnList;

                        // Refresh listview
                        lvStores.Items.Refresh();
                    }
                    else // If items exists
                    {
                        if (items != null)
                        {
                            bool itemAlreadyAdded = false; // use for boolean checking
                            foreach (AddListViewItem item in items) // loop through all items in listview
                            {
                                //Do some work with the item
                                MessageBox.Show(item.sID);

                                if (item.sID == SNewStoreTbid) // Check if new item already exists
                                {
                                    itemAlreadyAdded = true;
                                    break;
                                }

                                if (itemAlreadyAdded) // Show messagebox if it exists
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("ID needs to be unique, please respecify!", "Duplicate ID",
                                        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                                }
                                else // if it does not exist, create it from the textbox values
                                {
                                    lvColumnList.Add(
                                        new AddListViewItem() {sID = SNewStoreTbid, sName = SNewStoreTbName});
                                    lvStores.ItemsSource = lvColumnList;

                                    // refresh listview
                                    //ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView((List<AddListViewItem>)lvStores.ItemsSource);
                                    //view.Refresh();
                                    lvStores.Items.Refresh();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
 .....
        }

// Bind textbox values from NewStoreWindow
public class AddListViewItem
{
    public string sID { get; set; }
    public string sName { get; set; }
}
AddListViewItem item = new AddListViewItem
{
    sID = SNewStoreTbid, //SNewStoreTbid,
    sName = SNewStoreTbName //SNewStoreTbName
};
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, can't you simply add your new item to the ObservableCollection called `items` that you obtain via casting `lvStores.ItemsSource`? Why the need to create a new collection and transfer items from the old one to the new?

Comment: @StevenRands you probably haven't missed anything. I was trying and it didn't work. So I found a code that was kinda working.